# SSRS Manually select values passed to a multi-value subreport parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

In SSRS, I have a summary report, and when I click on any figures, it drills through a subreport that generate a list of skus.

I have setup the cells in the summary report and selected all Parameter for the drill through report.

For a multi-value parameter in the subreport, I want to manually select 2 out of 3 available values.

In the textbox property, under Action and parameters, What is the expression to specify the values I want to pass to my subreport?

[image: Text Box Properties]

Answer (score 0):

**1,2** - If your parameter is a integer. Don't use the expression with an equals sign, just `1,2` in the parameter value.

If your parameter is a string, I believe you need to double the double quotes.

```
""1"",""2""
```

You could also use the SPLIT function to create a string array from the hard-coded values:

```
=Split("1,2", ",")
```

Comment: Neither formula worked, but at the end, I just modified the list of available value on the subreport and added another value.  Then, in the dataset query, I adjusted the WHERE clause so that when the paramater has said value, the field IN ("1","2")

Answer (score 0):

Neither formula worked, but at the end, I just modified the list of available value on the subreport and added another value. Then, in the dataset query, I adjusted the WHERE clause so that when the paramater has said value, the field IN ("1","2")